# "The name 'Unauthorized' does not exist in the current context"

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to use `Unauthorized` method in my `Login` method, but I get an compiler error:

> "The name 'Unauthorized' does not exist in the current context"

Here is code of the class where the error occurs

```
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;
using API.Data;
using API.DTOs;
using API.Entities;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;


namespace API.Controllers
{
    public class AccountController : BaseApiController
    {
        private DataContext _context;
        public AccountController(DataContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        ...

        [HttpPost("login")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<AppUser>> Login(LoginDto logindto){
            var user = await _context.Users.SingleOrDefaultAsync(x => x.UserName == logindto.Username);

            if(user == null){
                return Unauthorized("invalid username"); <--And here
            }

            using var hmac = new HMACSHA512(user.PasswordSalt);

            var computedHash = hmac.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(logindto.Password));

            for(int i = 0; i < computedHash.Length; i++){
                if(computedHash[i] != user.PasswordHash[i]){
                    return Unauthorized();  <--Here
                 }
            }
        }

        private async Task<bool> UserExsist(string username)
        {
            return await _context.Users.AnyAsync(x => x.UserName == username.ToLower());
        }
    }
```

Here is the code for the base class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace API.Controllers
{

    [ApiController]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class BaseApiController
    {   
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you trying to use `Unauthorized`? What do you mean by using `Unauthorized`?

Comment: Where is `BaseApiController` coming from? Please [edit] your question to include the source code of that class.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I realized what the problem was. My base class was not derived from the ControllerBase class, which contains the Unauthorized() method I needed. I changed my base class to this one and the problem disappeared:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace API.Controllers
{

    [ApiController]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class BaseApiController : ControllerBase 
    {   
    }
}
```